# variational auto encoder loss goes down but does not reconstruct input. out of debugging ideas

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoders, pytorch, variational-autoencoder

My variational autoencoder seems to work for MNIST, but fails on slightly "harder" data.
By "fails" I mean there are at least two apparent problems:

1. Very poor reconstruction, for example sample reconstructions from the last epoch on validation set
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   without any regularization at all.
   The last reported losses from console are `val_loss=9.57e-5, train_loss=9.83e-5` which I thought would imply exact reconstructions.
2. validation loss is low (which does not seem to reflect the reconstruction), and **always lower than training loss** which is very suspicious.
   [image: losses]
   [image: losses2]

For MNIST everything looks fine (with less layers!).

[image: mnist recon]

I will give as much nformation as I can, since I am not sure what I should provide to help anyone help me.

---

Firstly, here is the **full code**
You will notice loss calculation and logging is very simple and straight forward and I can't seem to find what's wrong.

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from typing import List, Optional, Any
from pytorch_lightning.core.lightning import LightningModule
from Testing.Research.config.ConfigProvider import ConfigProvider
from pytorch_lightning import Trainer, seed_everything
from torch import optim
import os
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import TensorBoardLogger
# import tfmpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from Testing.Research.data_modules.MyDataModule import MyDataModule
from Testing.Research.data_modules.MNISTDataModule import MNISTDataModule
from Testing.Research.data_modules.CaseDataModule import CaseDataModule
import torchvision
from Testing.Research.config.paths import tb_logs_folder
from Testing.Research.config.paths import vae_checkpoints_path
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_checkpoint import ModelCheckpoint


class VAEFC(LightningModule):
    # see https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-variational-autoencoders-vaes-f70510919f73
    # for possible upgrades, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.02282.pdf
    # https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332179/how-to-weight-kld-loss-vs-reconstruction-loss-in-variational
    # -auto-encoder
    def __init__(self, encoder_layer_sizes: List, decoder_layer_sizes: List, config):
        super(VAEFC, self).__init__()
        self._config = config
        self.logger: Optional[TensorBoardLogger] = None
        self.save_hyperparameters()

        assert len(encoder_layer_sizes) >= 3, "must have at least 3 layers (2 hidden)"
        # encoder layers
        self._encoder_layers = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(1, len(encoder_layer_sizes) - 1):
            enc_layer = nn.Linear(encoder_layer_sizes[i - 1], encoder_layer_sizes[i])
            self._encoder_layers.append(enc_layer)

        # predict mean and covariance vectors
        self._mean_layer = nn.Linear(encoder_layer_sizes[
                                         len(encoder_layer_sizes) - 2],
                                     encoder_layer_sizes[len(encoder_layer_sizes) - 1])
        self._logvar_layer = nn.Linear(encoder_layer_sizes[
                                           len(encoder_layer_sizes) - 2],
                                       encoder_layer_sizes[len(encoder_layer_sizes) - 1])

        # decoder layers
        self._decoder_layers = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(1, len(decoder_layer_sizes)):
            dec_layer = nn.Linear(decoder_layer_sizes[i - 1], decoder_layer_sizes[i])
            self._decoder_layers.append(dec_layer)

        self._recon_function = nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')
        self._last_val_batch = {}

    def _encode(self, x):
        for i in range(len(self._encoder_layers)):
            layer = self._encoder_layers[i]
            x = F.relu(layer(x))

        mean_output = self._mean_layer(x)
        logvar_output = self._logvar_layer(x)
        return mean_output, logvar_output

    def _reparametrize(self, mu, logvar):
        if not self.training:
            return mu
        std = logvar.mul(0.5).exp_()
        if std.is_cuda:
            eps = torch.FloatTensor(std.size()).cuda().normal_()
        else:
            eps = torch.FloatTensor(std.size()).normal_()
        reparameterized = eps.mul(std).add_(mu)
        return reparameterized

    def _decode(self, z):
        for i in range(len(self._decoder_layers) - 1):
            layer = self._decoder_layers[i]
            z = F.relu((layer(z)))

        decoded = self._decoder_layers[len(self._decoder_layers) - 1](z)
        # decoded = F.sigmoid(self._decoder_layers[len(self._decoder_layers)-1](z))
        return decoded

    def _loss_function(self, recon_x, x, mu, logvar, reconstruction_function):
        """
        recon_x: generating images
        x: origin images
        mu: latent mean
        logvar: latent log variance
        """
        binary_cross_entropy = reconstruction_function(recon_x, x)  # mse loss TODO see if mse or cross entropy
        # loss = 0.5 * sum(1 + log(sigma^2) - mu^2 - sigma^2)
        kld_element = mu.pow(2).add_(logvar.exp()).mul_(-1).add_(1).add_(logvar)
        kld = torch.sum(kld_element).mul_(-0.5)
        # KL divergence Kullback–Leibler divergence, regularization term for VAE
        # It is a measure of how different two probability distributions are different from each other.
        # We are trying to force the distributions closer while keeping the reconstruction loss low.
        # see https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-variational-autoencoders-vaes-f70510919f73

        # read on weighting the regularization term here:
        # https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332179/how-to-weight-kld-loss-vs-reconstruction-loss-in-variational
        # -auto-encoder
        return binary_cross_entropy + kld * self._config.regularization_factor

    def _parse_batch_by_dataset(self, batch, batch_index):
        if self._config.dataset == "toy":
            (orig_batch, noisy_batch), label_batch = batch
            # TODO put in the noise here and not in the dataset?
        elif self._config.dataset == "mnist":
            orig_batch, label_batch = batch
            orig_batch = orig_batch.reshape(-1, 28 * 28)
            noisy_batch = orig_batch
        elif self._config.dataset == "case":
            orig_batch, label_batch = batch

            orig_batch = orig_batch.float().reshape(
                    -1,
                    len(self._config.case.feature_list) * self._config.case.frames_per_pd_sample
            )
            noisy_batch = orig_batch
        else:
            raise ValueError("invalid dataset")
        noisy_batch = noisy_batch.view(noisy_batch.size(0), -1)

        return orig_batch, noisy_batch, label_batch

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        orig_batch, noisy_batch, label_batch = self._parse_batch_by_dataset(batch, batch_idx)

        recon_batch, mu, logvar = self.forward(noisy_batch)

        loss = self._loss_function(
                recon_batch,
                orig_batch, mu, logvar,
                reconstruction_function=self._recon_function
        )
        # self.logger.experiment.add_scalars("losses", {"train_loss": loss})
        tb = self.logger.experiment
        tb.add_scalars("losses", {"train_loss": loss}, global_step=self.current_epoch)
        # self.logger.experiment.add_scalar("train_loss", loss, self.current_epoch)
        if batch_idx == len(self.train_dataloader()) - 2:
            # https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/tensorboard/writer.html#SummaryWriter.add_embedding
            # noisy_batch = noisy_batch.detach()
            # recon_batch = recon_batch.detach()
            # last_batch_plt = matplotlib.figure.Figure()  # read https://github.com/wookayin/tensorflow-plot
            # ax = last_batch_plt.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
            # ax.scatter(orig_batch[:, 0], orig_batch[:, 1], label="original")
            # ax.scatter(noisy_batch[:, 0], noisy_batch[:, 1], label="noisy")
            # ax.scatter(recon_batch[:, 0], recon_batch[:, 1], label="reconstructed")
            # ax.legend(loc="upper left")
            # self.logger.experiment.add_figure(f"original last batch, epoch {self.current_epoch}", last_batch_plt)
            # tb.add_embedding(orig_batch, global_step=self.current_epoch, metadata=label_batch)
            pass
        self.logger.experiment.flush()
        self.log("train_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        return loss

    def _plot_batches(self, orig_batch, noisy_batch, label_batch, batch_idx, recon_batch, mu, logvar):
        # orig_batch_view = orig_batch.reshape(-1, self._config.case.frames_per_pd_sample,
        # len(self._config.case.feature_list))
        #
        # plt.figure()
        # plt.plot(orig_batch_view[11, :, 0].detach().cpu().numpy(), label="feature 0")
        # plt.legend(loc="upper left")
        # plt.show()

        tb = self.logger.experiment
        if self._config.dataset == "mnist":
            orig_batch -= orig_batch.min()
            orig_batch /= orig_batch.max()
            recon_batch -= recon_batch.min()
            recon_batch /= recon_batch.max()

            orig_grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(orig_batch.view(-1, 1, 28, 28))
            val_recon_grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(recon_batch.view(-1, 1, 28, 28))

            tb.add_image("original_val", orig_grid, global_step=self.current_epoch)
            tb.add_image("reconstruction_val", val_recon_grid, global_step=self.current_epoch)

            label_img = orig_batch.view(-1, 1, 28, 28)
            pass
        elif self._config.dataset == "case":
            orig_batch_view = orig_batch.reshape(-1, self._config.case.frames_per_pd_sample,
                                                 len(self._config.case.feature_list)).transpose(1, 2)
            recon_batch_view = recon_batch.reshape(-1, self._config.case.frames_per_pd_sample,
                                                   len(self._config.case.feature_list)).transpose(1, 2)

            # plt.figure()
            # plt.plot(orig_batch_view[11, 0, :].detach().cpu().numpy())
            # plt.show()
            # pass

            n_samples = orig_batch_view.shape[0]
            n_plots = min(n_samples, 4)
            first_sample_idx = 0

            # TODO either plotting or data problem
            fig, axs = plt.subplots(n_plots, 1)
            for sample_idx in range(n_plots):
                for feature_idx, (orig_feature, recon_feature) in enumerate(
                        zip(orig_batch_view[sample_idx + first_sample_idx, :, :],
                            recon_batch_view[sample_idx + first_sample_idx, :, :])):
                    i = feature_idx
                    if i > 0: continue  # or scale issues don't allow informative plotting

                    # plt.figure()
                    # plt.plot(orig_feature.detach().cpu().numpy(), label=f'orig{i}, sample{sample_idx}')
                    # plt.legend(loc='upper left')
                    # pass

                    axs[sample_idx].plot(orig_feature.detach().cpu().numpy(), label=f'orig{i}, sample{sample_idx}')
                    axs[sample_idx].plot(recon_feature.detach().cpu().numpy(), label=f'recon{i}, sample{sample_idx}')
                    # sample{sample_idx}')
                    axs[sample_idx].legend(loc='upper left')
                pass
            # plt.show()

            tb.add_figure("recon_vs_orig", fig, global_step=self.current_epoch, close=True)

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        orig_batch, noisy_batch, label_batch = self._parse_batch_by_dataset(batch, batch_idx)

        recon_batch, mu, logvar = self.forward(noisy_batch)

        loss = self._loss_function(
                recon_batch,
                orig_batch, mu, logvar,
                reconstruction_function=self._recon_function
        )

        tb = self.logger.experiment
        # can probably speed up training by waiting for epoch end for data copy from gpu
        # see https://sagivtech.com/2017/09/19/optimizing-pytorch-training-code/
        tb.add_scalars("losses", {"val_loss": loss}, global_step=self.current_epoch)

        label_img = None
        if len(orig_batch) > 2:
            self._last_val_batch = {
                "orig_batch": orig_batch,
                "noisy_batch": noisy_batch,
                "label_batch": label_batch,
                "batch_idx": batch_idx,
                "recon_batch": recon_batch,
                "mu": mu,
                "logvar": logvar
            }
        # self._plot_batches(orig_batch, noisy_batch, label_batch, batch_idx, recon_batch, mu, logvar)

        outputs = {"val_loss":  loss, "recon_batch": recon_batch, "label_batch": label_batch,
                   "label_img": label_img}
        self.log("val_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        return outputs

    def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs: List[Any]) -> None:
        first_batch_dict = outputs[-1]

        self._plot_batches(
                self._last_val_batch["orig_batch"],
                self._last_val_batch["noisy_batch"],
                self._last_val_batch["label_batch"],
                self._last_val_batch["batch_idx"],
                self._last_val_batch["recon_batch"],
                self._last_val_batch["mu"],
                self._last_val_batch["logvar"]
        )
        self.log(name="VAEFC_val_loss_epoch_end", value={"val_loss": first_batch_dict["val_loss"]})

    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        orig_batch, noisy_batch, label_batch = self._parse_batch_by_dataset(batch, batch_idx)

        recon_batch, mu, logvar = self.forward(noisy_batch)

        loss = self._loss_function(
                recon_batch,
                orig_batch, mu, logvar,
                reconstruction_function=self._recon_function
        )

        tb = self.logger.experiment
        tb.add_scalars("losses", {"test_loss": loss}, global_step=self.global_step)

        return {"test_loss": loss, "mus": mu, "labels": label_batch, "images": orig_batch}

    def test_epoch_end(self, outputs: List):
        tb = self.logger.experiment

        avg_loss = torch.stack([x['test_loss'] for x in outputs]).mean()
        self.log(name="test_epoch_end", value={"test_loss_avg": avg_loss})

        if self._config.dataset == "mnist":
            tb.add_embedding(
                    mat=torch.cat([o["mus"] for o in outputs]),
                    metadata=torch.cat([o["labels"] for o in outputs]).detach().cpu().numpy(),
                    label_img=torch.cat([o["images"] for o in outputs]).view(-1, 1, 28, 28),
                    global_step=self.global_step,
            )

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self._config.learning_rate)
        return optimizer

    def forward(self, x):
        mu, logvar = self._encode(x)
        z = self._reparametrize(mu, logvar)
        decoded = self._decode(z)
        return decoded, mu, logvar


def train_vae(config, datamodule, latent_dim, dec_layer_sizes, enc_layer_sizes):
    model = VAEFC(config=config, encoder_layer_sizes=enc_layer_sizes, decoder_layer_sizes=dec_layer_sizes)

    logger = TensorBoardLogger(save_dir=tb_logs_folder, name='VAEFC', default_hp_metric=False)
    logger.hparams = config

    checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(dirpath=vae_checkpoints_path)
    trainer = Trainer(deterministic=config.is_deterministic,
                      # auto_lr_find=config.auto_lr_find,
                      # log_gpu_memory='all',
                      # min_epochs=99999,
                      max_epochs=config.num_epochs,
                      default_root_dir=vae_checkpoints_path,
                      logger=logger,
                      callbacks=[checkpoint_callback],
                      gpus=1
                      )
    # trainer.tune(model)
    trainer.fit(model, datamodule=datamodule)
    best_model_path = checkpoint_callback.best_model_path
    print("done training vae with lightning")
    print(f"best model path = {best_model_path}")
    return trainer


def run_trained_vae(trainer):
    # https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_set.html
    # (1) load the best checkpoint automatically (lightning tracks this for you)
    trainer.test()

    # (2) don't load a checkpoint, instead use the model with the latest weights
    # trainer.test(ckpt_path=None)

    # (3) test using a specific checkpoint
    # trainer.test(ckpt_path='/path/to/my_checkpoint.ckpt')

    # (4) test with an explicit model (will use this model and not load a checkpoint)
    # trainer.test(model)
```

---

**Parameters**

I am getting very similar results for any combination of parameters I am (manually) using. Maybe I didn't try something.

```
num_epochs: 40
batch_size: 32
learning_rate: 0.0001
auto_lr_find: False

noise_factor: 0.1
regularization_factor: 0.0

train_size: 0.8
val_size: 0.1
num_workers: 1

dataset: "case" # toy, mnnist, case
mnist:
  enc_layer_sizes: [784, 512,]
  dec_layer_sizes: [512, 784]
  latent_dim: 25
  n_classes: 10
  classifier_layers: [20, 10]
toy:
  enc_layer_sizes: [2, 200, 200, 200]
  dec_layer_sizes: [200, 200, 200, 2]
  latent_dim: 8
  centers_radius: 4.0
  n_clusters: 10
  cluster_size: 5000
case:
  #enc_layer_sizes: [ 1800, 600, 300, 100 ]
  #dec_layer_sizes: [ 100, 300, 600, 1800 ]
  #frames_per_pd_sample: 600

  enc_layer_sizes: [ 10, 600, 300, 300 ]
  dec_layer_sizes: [ 600, 300, 300, 10 ]
  frames_per_pd_sample: 10

  latent_dim: 300
  n_classes: 10
  classifier_layers: [ 20, 10 ] # unused right now.

  feature_list:
    #- V_0_0 # 0, X
    #- V_0_1 # 0, Y
    #- V_0_2 # 0, Z
    - pads_0
  enc_kernel_sizes: [] # for conv
  end_strides: []
  dec_kernel_sizes: []
  dec_strides: []

is_deterministic: False

real_data_pd_dir: "D:/pressure_pd"
case_dir: "real_case_20_min"
case_file: "pressure_data_0.pkl"
```

---

**Data**

For Mnist everything works fine.

When changing to my specific data, results are as above.

The data is a **time series**, of several features. To dumb this down even more, I am feeding just a single feature, sliced to equal-length chunks, and fed into the input layer as a vector.
The fact that the data is a time series could maybe help modeling in the future, but for now I want to just refer to it as chunks of data, which I believe I am doing.

code:

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
from Testing.Research.config.ConfigProvider import ConfigProvider
import os
import pickle
import pandas as pd
from typing import Tuple
import numpy as np


class CaseDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path):
        super(CaseDataset, self).__init__()
        self._path = path

        self._config = ConfigProvider.get_config()
        self.frames_per_pd_sample = self._config.case.frames_per_pd_sample
        self._load_case_from_pkl()
        self.__len = len(self._full) // self.frames_per_pd_sample  # discard last non full batch

    def _load_case_from_pkl(self):
        assert os.path.isfile(self._path)
        with open(self._path, "rb") as f:
            p = pickle.load(f)

        self._full: pd.DataFrame = p["full"]
        self._subsampled: pd.DataFrame = p["subsampled"]
        self._misc: pd.DataFrame = p["misc"]

        feature_list = self._config.case.feature_list
        self._features_df = self._full[feature_list].copy()

        # normalize from -1 to 1
        features_to_normalize = self._features_df.columns
        self._features_df[features_to_normalize] = \
            self._features_df[features_to_normalize].apply(lambda x: (((x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min())) * 2) - 1)

        pass

    def __len__(self):
        # number of samples in the dataset
        return self.__len

    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> Tuple[np.array, np.array]:
        data_item = self._features_df.iloc[index * self.frames_per_pd_sample: (index + 1) * self.frames_per_pd_sample, :].values
        label = 0.0
        # plt.figure()
        # plt.plot(data_item[:, 0], label="feature 0")
        # plt.legend(loc="upper left")
        # plt.show()
        return data_item, label
```

The amount of time-steps per batch does not seem to affect convergence.

**Train test val split**

is done like so:

```
import os
from pytorch_lightning import LightningDataModule
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
from torchvision.transforms import transforms
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data import Subset
from Testing.Research.config.paths import mnist_data_download_folder
from Testing.Research.datasets.real_cases.CaseDataset import CaseDataset
from typing import Optional


class CaseDataModule(LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self, config, path):
        super().__init__()
        self._config = config
        self._path = path

        self._train_dataset: Optional[Subset] = None
        self._val_dataset: Optional[Subset] = None
        self._test_dataset: Optional[Subset] = None

    def prepare_data(self):
        pass

    def setup(self, stage):
        # transform
        transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
        full_dataset = CaseDataset(self._path)

        train_size = int(self._config.train_size * len(full_dataset))
        val_size = int(self._config.val_size * len(full_dataset))
        test_size = len(full_dataset) - train_size - val_size
        train, val, test = torch.utils.data.random_split(full_dataset, [train_size, val_size, test_size])

        # assign to use in dataloaders
        self._full_dataset = full_dataset
        self._train_dataset = train
        self._val_dataset = val
        self._test_dataset = test

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self._train_dataset, batch_size=self._config.batch_size, num_workers=self._config.num_workers)

    def val_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self._val_dataset, batch_size=self._config.batch_size, num_workers=self._config.num_workers)

    def test_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self._test_dataset, batch_size=self._config.batch_size, num_workers=self._config.num_workers)
```

**Questions**

1. I believe having the validation loss consistently lower than the train loss shows something is very wrong here, but I can't put my finger on what, or come up with how to verify this.
2. How can I just make the model auto-encode the data correctly? Basicaly, I would want it to learn the identity function, and for the loss to reflect that.
3. **The loss does not seem to reflect the reconstruction. I think this is probably the most fundamental issue**

---

**My thoughts**

1. Try a convolutional net instead of FC? maybe it would be able to better learn features?
2. Out of ideas :(

---

Will provide any lacking information.

Comment: I am just wondering if have you found any solution for the problem, I am also facing a similar sort of problem with my VAE model.

Comment: @NadiaTanzeem Can't remember, it was over 2 years ago, sorry. The project was dumped. Today, I would use some out of the box algorithm as a first step, rather than banging my head alone.